# How can i add multiple where condition in loop using firebase and angular?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I am trying to add dynamic conditions on firebase query. But somehow not working. I also try `chatgpt` but that is also not provide me the best solution. Please help me to fix my issue.

> Type 'CollectionReference' is not assignable to type 'Query'.

[image]

```
getListing(): Observable<Listing[]> {
    return this.afs
      .collection<Listing>('listing', (ref) => {
        let query: firebase.firestore.Query =ref;
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(this.searchFilter)) {
         query= query.where(key, "==", value)
        }
        return ref.orderBy('createdAt', 'asc')
      })
      .snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        map((actions) =>
          actions.map((action) => {
            const id = action.payload.doc.id;
            const data = action.payload.doc.data() as Listing;
            return { id, ...data } as Listing;
          })
        )
      );
  }
```

Any solution appreciated!

Comment: Which line gives that error message?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i attached the image you can check.

Answer (score 1):

As follow this [example in GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/compat/firestore/querying-collections.md#example-app) by defining query as `firebase.firestore.CollectionReference | firebase.firestore.Query` type should be able to resolve the issue.

```
let query: firebase.firestore.CollectionReference | firebase.firestore.Query = ref;

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(this.searchFilter)) {
  query = query.where(key, "==", value)
}

return query.orderBy('createdAt', 'asc');
```

Comment: I already tried this, but i got some type errors.

Comment: What type error did you get? Please provide more info. Thanks.

Comment: `No overload mathes this call`. Please check this error

Comment: Still, the provided error message is unclear. Which line gets this issue and what is the complete error message. Please attach in the question. Thanks.

Comment: I attached the image u can check now

Answer (score 0):

After lot of struggle. Finally i am able to solve the issue by my own.

```
getListing(filter: Filter | undefined = undefined): Observable<Listing[]> {
    return new Observable((observer) => {
      let collectionRef = this.afs.collection<Listing>('listing').ref;
      let query = collectionRef.orderBy('createdAt', 'asc');
      if (filter) {
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(filter)) {
          query = query.where(key, "==", value)
        }
      }
      query.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
        const data: Listing[] = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          const id = doc.id;
          const listing = doc.data() as Listing;
          data.push({ id, ...listing });
        });
        observer.next(data);
        observer.complete();
      });
    });
  }
```